# DateTime.Now in .NET sometimes wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

In my web app, when user clicks a "START" button, I record the time by `DateTime.Now` and save this to sql server db.
This operation is used many times in a day. And sometimes, one or two days, it record the wrong time.
I traced all my code to ensure that there's nowhere in my code update this column value.
Notice that, my web app is running entirely on client machine (IIS, sql server express).
I'm thinking that maybe DateTime.Now recored the wrong time.
Please give some suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong time"? Off by a second? Century?

Comment: It's possible since it's based on the user's machine that the different time zone makes it a different day. Or maybe you know that's **not** the case.

Comment: datetime.now return date and time of the server which run your code . it not record the time of browser machine . can you please modify your question by giving example .

Comment: @HirenDhaduk You're assuming ASP.net. I'm guessing this is WinForms.

Comment: @MillDoll, can you please also tag the question with the language (C#, VB.net) and the framework (WPF, WinForms, ASP.net) you're using?

Comment: Question is about "my web app is running entirely on client machine (IIS, sql server express)". that means this is web form application.

Comment: If you're storing to the database, you really should be storing `DateTime.UtcNow`. Convert it to local time for display.

Comment: My web app is written by asp.net mvc3, and use Sql server express. It is a small app so i can deploy on to windows 7 machine. So I expect DateTime.Now is recording the current date time in this machine. I don't think my client changed the time in their machine.

Comment: The problem is sometimes, it record the wrong value.

Comment: First, I think maybe my code in somewhere has updated this column value. But there's one place in code create this value when click "START". So next, I wondering about if DateTime.Now return the wrong value and asked people if they have encountered this same problme!

Comment: I save DateTime.Now value in 2 columns, not just 1. "StartTime" and "CreatedOn" column and they have exactly the same value.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that, somewhere along the line, for some unaccountable reason, you take this perfectly good `DateTime` value and convert it to a string. And then later force some other piece of code (maybe down in the database) to convert it back into a `datetime`. And it's the disagreements between these two pieces of (unnecessary) code that create the issue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yes. First, when click "START" I get DateTime.Now value to store in DB an return a string represent this time to show in the GUI. But after this time, I use the value in DB for calculation and not update this value anywhere. I traced all the code but couldn't see a case that update this value.

Comment: @MillDol - I was suggesting that somewhere, in the process of *storing* that date that there was a string conversion. Can you show the code that stores this date in the database?

Comment: @Daminen, it's simple.                                             var bill = new Bill { TenantId = CurrentTenantId,
                UserId = CurrentUserId,
                Status = (short)((TableStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(TableStatus), status, false)),
                StartTime = DateTime.Now,
                Code = code,
                TableId = id,
                IsPaid = false,
                IsActive = true
            };
            this._billRepo.Add(bill);
            return Json(bill.StartTime.ToHourFormat(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: @MillDol - that code doesn't include anything about a database - and please *edit* your question to include code - you can then hit the `{}` button and it gets formatted nicely and we can actually read it.

Comment: Yes, for sure i can't post code here because it's quite scatterd if you want to see the flow the recording and updating the time. I've just post this question to ask if anyone get the same problem with Datetime.Now. If not, maybe my code has problem and i must try to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it's displaying the wrong value? That should help us track down the problem.

Comment: @Iain Galloway, I knew it because the flow of my app.

Comment: I have solved it by an unnatural way. The final thought of me about this problem is maybe my app may cause leak memory. My app is implemented as a single page app with a lot of js and this app is used with very high frequency. So I put into my app the "Refresh" functionality and told user to refresh after they operate a lot. And in server side, I set app pool recycling in 4h. And in last 4 days this bug didn't happen again.

Comment: Hi all, with the "Refresh" functionality, my app has worked all the time. But It still happens, 2-3 weeks/time. So I thought maybe there are 2 causes: 1) The strange behavior happended because the leak memory of js. 2) The time is modified by another soft/app on the desktop that deployed my web app. But for me it's too vague. What your thoughts on this? Thanks.

Comment: If you have interested, I can give you the account to run my web app to understand the flow. because it's also a SaaS web app.

Answer (score 2):

The .Net `DateTime.Now` gets the time from whichever computer the code is executing on.

I'd suggest that you want to get your date and time from your database server instead. Assuming that is SQL Server, you'd use a statement like:

```
select getdate()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

Comment: yes, I want to record the current date time in the clock of the machine and record it to db for calcuting later, I persist it by using Entity Framework. From that point i've just get the value from db.

Comment: There will be a bug in your code. I suggest you post your code in the question above.

Comment: Probably your best strategy then is to try and reproduce this by writing a sample app that only has the minimum code in it. By doing this you will almost certainly find what the problem is by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Derek's solution, I would suggest that you look at the point in the code where you cache the DateTime.Now() var. It could be that you're capturing this at the start of your code loigc and therefore, depending on the conditions, the elapsed time between getting the datetime and passing it to the server could vary widely.

My suggestion (in the absence of code), would be to ensure that the datetime cache to a variable is literally the last action before calling sqlserver (unless of course, it's important to monitor the duration of the method -in which case, take two DateTime variables, one at the top and one at the bottom of the method and pass both).